# Software Updater shows "Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection" [18.04 LTS]

Tags: 18.04, update-manager, repository, lts

I know this question has been brought up ad nauseam, but I want to be sure I make the right changes to fix it. I'm pretty sure I need to change some of the settings in Software & Updates, but which ones? Or is there something else I need to resolve? Here's the terminal message that displays when I run `sudo apt-get update` along with the Software & Updates menu.

[image]

edit: included text.

```
nicholas@klaus:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for nicholas: 
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:10 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                          
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu bionic Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: If your message was text, I could copy & paste the URL to check it supports 'bionic' (or 18.04, for example pasting it into a browser & looking to see there is a folder titled 'bionic' in dists/).  I can't copy/paste from a picture so you'll have to do the checks, and remove if it doesn't support your bionic release. I'd suggest checking your release is supported before (not after) you add PPAs.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the text.

Comment: Copy & paste the url into a browser - when you open the dists/ folder (ie. navigate to http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu/dists/) you'll note support for saucy-xenial - ie. support in the PPA ended at 16.04  (*no folders for any later release exist there*).  It needs removal.  *fyi:  before you add the PPA you can check the PPA's main page & view supported... but from the URL in error messages I find this method faster*

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: So just to clarify for future reference, if my current release isn't listed under 
`ppa.launchpad.net/*/*/ubuntu/dist` that means it is no longer supported and should be removed? Does this issue/fix only apply to PPA or does it apply to missing/unsupported  repository files in general?